# Springfox 404 Error When Testing API from Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Investigating Springfox and Swagger UI, but I am facing an issue. I am using the Spring Boot REST example project as the foundation for my PoC. I'm running JDK 8 and the project leverages Gradle.

First, here are the file contents for the project:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.2.2")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.2.2")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**Greeting.java**

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package hello;

import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static springfox.documentation.schema.AlternateTypeRules.newRule;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ResponseMessageBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.schema.ModelRef;
import springfox.documentation.schema.WildcardType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    public Docket greetingApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SPRING_WEB)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/")
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
            .alternateTypeRules(newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
                typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
                newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                    .code(500)
                    .message("500 message")
                    .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error"))
                    .build()))
            .enableUrlTemplating(true);
    }

}
```

Here is the issue I am facing. When I build and run the application, I can successfully navigate to the Swagger UI page (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html). When I expand greeting-controller, I see the different methods and expand "get /greeting{?name}". The Get section has the following content:

```
Response Class (Status 200)

Model

{
  "content": "string",
  "id": 0
}

Response Content Type: */*

Parameters
parameter = name, value = World, parameter type = query, data type = string
```

When I click the "Try It Out" button, I see the following:

```
curl = curl -X GET --header "Accept: */*" "http://localhost:8080/greeting{?name}?name=World"

request url = http://localhost:8080/greeting{?name}?name=World

repsonse body = {
  "timestamp": 1446418006199,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/greeting%7B"
}

response code = 404

response headers = {
  "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
  "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Sun, 01 Nov 2015 22:46:46 GMT"
}
```

At first glance, it looks like for some reason that Springfox/Swagger is not correctly replacing the placeholder for {?name}. My question is, how do I configure it to do so, if that is in fact the issue, so that I can successfully test out the service from the Swagger UI page?

Comment: yep as you see in the response body, it is trying to open the url `/greeting%7B` with `%7B` being the `{` just before `?name`}. Try using `enableUrlTemplating(false)` when you create the Docket (you are using a RequestParam not PathVariable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Application` class changing the `enableUrlTemplating` to false will fix your problem.

```java
@Bean
public Docket greetingApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SPRING_WEB)
        //...
        .enableUrlTemplating(false);
}
```

Just a little bit of background on that flag. That flag is to support [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) without which operations that differ only by query string parameters [will not show up correctly per spec](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/866). In the next iteration of the swagger spec there are plans to address that issue. That is the reason for `enableUrlTemplating` to be marked as an [incubating feature](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-spring-web/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.java#L396).